# Filter by date from a view does not return all records

Tags: mysql, view, mariadb, where-clause, mariadb-10.3

I have to make a query on a view filtering results by date bigger than a value.

Using the program I noticed that I was not receiving all the results I was expecting.

I made some test to try to replicate the issue and I had the same behavior "exploding" the view in a nested query. I have to use the view because I need some calculated fields, in the example shown below the view/nested query is not useful because I removed all the unnecessary fields and joins to make the query more readable.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT fat_id, fat_date, fat_id_visibility_uo, fat_tipo_doc
    FROM rm_fatture 
    WHERE fat_data_fin = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY fat_id
) _master
WHERE fat_id_visibility_uo = 113960
AND fat_date >= '2019-12-01';

returns 2 records instead of the 6 expected:

| fat_id | fat_date | fat_id_visibility_uo | fat_tipo_doc | 
| 110123 | 2019-12-05 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 110134 | 2019-12-02 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA |
```

If I change the where clause using date on the field **"date(fat_date) >= '2019-12-01"** the query works as expected and returns all data:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT fat_id, fat_date, fat_id_visibility_uo, fat_tipo_doc
    FROM rm_fatture 
    WHERE fat_data_fin = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY fat_id
) _master
WHERE fat_id_visibility_uo = 113960
AND date(fat_date) >= '2019-12-01';

returns:

| fat_id | fat_date | fat_id_visibility_uo | fat_tipo_doc | 
| 109846 | 2019-12-31 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 109924 | 2019-12-31 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 110043 | 2019-12-05 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 110119 | 2019-12-05 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 110123 | 2019-12-05 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA | 
| 110134 | 2019-12-02 | 113960 | FATTURA IMMEDIATA |
```

The select also returns the correct records if I order the nested query by the same field:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT fat_id, fat_date, fat_id_visibility_uo, fat_tipo_doc
    FROM rm_fatture 
    WHERE fat_data_fin = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY fat_id
    ORDER BY fat_date
) _master
WHERE fat_id_visibility_uo = 113960
AND fat_date >= '2019-12-01';
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.3.18 on Centos 7.

I've found a solution but honestly it looks like a MariaDB bug to me I would like to be sure about the cause to avoid future problems.

Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: What is the data type of `fat_date`?

Comment: Looks like a bug. An ORDER BY in the subquery shouldn't change the result. Please create a full script, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSpiegel, fat_date type is DATE. I'll make a script and post it here

Comment: Just realized that you use the GROUP BY clause in an invalid way. What you do in the subquery doesn't make sense. You cannot select `fat_date` but only GROUP BY  `fat_id`.

Comment: You're right, using the group by I have all records but I still have some doubts: in the first query if I put in the outside where fat_id = 110119 that is NOT returned in the first results, I receive it in output. At the same time trying to replicate the issue creating the script I still have different answers. How could the result be so unpredictable?

Comment: Ok I found it on MariaDB documentation. The MariaDB default setting does not include the sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY that disallow selecting fields that are not included in group by list and aren't in an aggregation function. Unlikely it does not throw an error but (and I still consider it a bug) it returns unpredictable results with wrong queries. I will enable it in my configuration and correct all the (hopefully few) wrong queries. Thank you @PaulSpiegel for your help!

Comment: I would use ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in MariaDB with caution. Unlike MySQL MariaDB doesn't detect functional dependency and will thow an error for some deterministic queries which run on MySQL.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a bug; please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for each of your queries.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE...`  Is `fat_id` the PRIMARY KEY?